# RefineryCMS Changing Site Name in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I have a refinery site up on heroku and, in order to change the site name I have been going to my local copy, changing `config.site_name`, adding the new config file to my git repository, and doing `git push heroku master`.  Though I don't anticipate having to change the site name that many more times (I have a client who is still deciding on a final site name),  I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this (I tried to figure out if this was a config option I could just change from the terminal in heroku but to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to add new model 'site_setting' for adding some additional settings. So you can add one column ie site_name. So admin can dynamically add/update the name of site by providing simple UI to insert the name of site.

Remaining task is to add that object at site_bar.html.erb

I hope this work for you.